# How to tell JAXB to ignore the properties from the parent class

Tags: jaxb

I am facing the following problems with JAXB: It looks like JAXB is analysing properties from the most deep child class to parent, and child property has a priority. I would like to change somehow this behaviour. In particular:

The child class:

```
package test.sub;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class BasicDocument {

    private String comment;

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String cost) {
        this.comment = cost;
    }
}
```

The parent class:

```
package test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringStyle;

import test.sub.BasicDocument;

@XmlRootElement(name="Description", namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
class Document extends BasicDocument {

    private String identifier;

    @XmlElement(name = "identifier", namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/terms/")
    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public void setIdentifier(String identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    @Override
    @XmlElement(name = "abstract", namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/terms/")
    public String getComment() {
        return super.getComment();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);
    }
}
```

Marshalling works fine:

```
Document document = new Document();

document.setIdentifier("12A");
document.setComment("special");

StringWriter w = new StringWriter();

jaxbContext.createMarshaller().marshal(document, new StreamResult(w));

System.out.println(w);
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:Description xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">
    <abstract>special</abstract>
    <identifier>12A</identifier>
</ns2:Description>
```

But marshalling ignores the property which is in child `BasicDocument` class (`t.xml` is exactly the XML above):

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Document.class);

Document document = (Document) jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(Document.class.getResourceAsStream("t.xml"));

System.out.println("out: " + document);
```

Output:

```
out: Document[identifier=12A,comment=<null>]
```

Expected:

```
out: Document[identifier=12A,comment=special]
```

Basically `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` on `BasicDocument` (see [Ignore a parent class when Serializing to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728341)) had no effect. Also creating `package-info.java` in package `test.sub` (see [@XmlTransient on third-party or external super class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8540344/267197)) like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
package test.sub;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
```

had no effect. Only `@XmlTransient public class BasicDocument` worked. Ideally I would like not to add any annotation on child and control this behaviour only via `package-info.java`. How can I do this?

Tested on JDK 1.6.0_27, and additionally with JAXB 2.2.4-1 runtime in classpath.

Is it feature or bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add the `setComment` method to the `Document` class.  Without it, it is being treated as a write-only property even though the method exists on a parent class.

```
public void setComment(String comment) {
    super.setComment(comment);
}
```

**Full Source for `Document`**

```
package test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringStyle;

import test.sub.BasicDocument;

@XmlRootElement(name="Description", namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
class Document extends BasicDocument {

    private String identifier;

    @XmlElement(name = "identifier", namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/terms/")
    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public void setIdentifier(String identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    @Override
    @XmlElement(name = "abstract", namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/terms/")
    public String getComment() {
        return super.getComment();
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        super.setComment(comment);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why `@XmlTransient` had a magic cure effect in this case?

Comment: @dma_k - `@XmlTransient` worked on the super class, because that tells the JAXB implementation to ignore it from the inheritance hierarchy and treat the properties as if they belong to the subclasses:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/ignoring-inheritance-with-xmltransient.html

Comment: I faced kind of "interesting behaviour" from JAXB. I have introduced an intermediate class `CommentHolder` in `BasicDocument` which holds `String comment` property. `BasicDocument` is added `CommentHolder getCommentHolder()` and `setCommentHolder(CommentHolder commentHolder)` in place of get/setComment. `Document` class was updated like following `String getComment() { return super.getCommentHolder().getComment(); }` and `void setComment(String comment) { super.getCommentHolder().setComment(comment); }` so its API is the same. JAXB now serializes `commentHolder` property. Is it normal? Thanks